# Radius of Convergence series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Hey can please someone show me how to get radius of convergence of this series?

$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1} \dfrac{\sqrt{n!}}n x^n$

i started with root test because of $x^n$ but then i have $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{n!}}{n}}$ which test is the best and why? how should i start?

Comment: Tell us what you have already done and explain where you are stuck. Edit you post; otherwise, it will be closed very fast. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: Always try the ratio test first.

Comment: i tried already as i told. can you please show me what to do next?

Comment: The ratio test should be enough to get you an answer here. What did you get as a result for the ratio? Maybe we can help you from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard way to show convergence of a power series, $\sum_{n=a}^\infty a_nx^n$, is the "ratio test" (you can also use the "root test" but I've never liked it!).  The series $\sum_{n=a}^\infty a_n$ for $a_n\ge 0$, converges if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}< 1$.  For power series, $\sum_{n=a}^\infty a_nx^n$, in particular,  that becomes $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}{a_nx^n}|=$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}||x|< 1$.

That requires that $|x|< \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$.
Calling that right side "R" so I don't have to keep writing it, that means the power series converges for x between -R and R. R is the "radius of convergence".

In your example, $a_n= \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n}$ so $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= $$\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}{n+1}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n!}}$$= \sqrt{\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}}\frac{n}{n+1}= \sqrt{n+1}\frac{n}{n+1}$.  The limit of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is 1 while $\sqrt{n+1}$ is "infinity".  The series converges only for x= 0 so the "radius of convergence" is $\frac{1}{\infty}= 0$.

Comment: You discuss a sufficient condition for convergence, but not for divergence, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With the ratio test we get $$|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \sqrt{n+1} |x|$$ which diverges to infinity unless $x=0$

You should take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists, the radius of convergence is given by
$$
R= \lim\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|} = \lim \frac{\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{n}}{\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}{n+1}} = \lim\sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}} = 0.
$$

The series only converges of $x=0$.